# Can Luigi file targets be properly managed using pandas file i/o functions instead of open/close

Tags: pandas, csv, luigi

I have a script that relies heavily on pandas file i/o functions like read_csv(), to_csv(), etc. with the many custom parameters they offer.

**Can these be used in a luigi pipeline for local file targets?**

I want to convert it to a luigi pipeline but every example I have seen uses open/close python i/o with custom parsing.

I hear that the luigi target object functionality relies specifically on target.close() or 'with' for the dependency tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `LocalTarget` can be used with the output of arbitrary code. The file tracking relies on the `exists()` method. `open()` is just a convenience method.